# How to display only selected fields at runtime and display as a crystal report in c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I am developing an application in winforms for generating crystal reports at
  dynamic.

Means i provided checkboxes on front end for each filed in the database table.
  So if the user selects only particular fields at runtime i want to show the
  crystal report dynamically.

So i designed database connection using oledb in sql and i passed the sql 
  query to the database i got the data depending up on user selection fields
  everything is fine.

I took the parameter fields in my crystal report as col1,col2 and so on col5
  because i have only 5 fileds in  my table.

But when click on "View Report" button in my form it is always ask
  "Enter parameter values" on prompt message at runtime.

under View Report button code is:

```
            OleDbDataAdapter adepter =
            new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);



            adepter.Fill(ds,"customer");

            crRprt.SetDataSource(ds);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crRprt;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

What is the issue for asking that prompt message? Enter parameter values?

Note : I think i don't know how to add parameter fileds may be is this the
  problem for me?

Can you tell me the issue?
  Can anyone help? Thanks